# Why do I have to type enter to exit my bash script?

Tags: bash, shell

When I run my script, I am forced to type enter key, in order exit the
script after it completes. Here's my script:

```
log_file=/tmp/log.out

rm -f $log_file

setup()
{
  exec > >(tee -a ${log_file} )
  exec 2> >(tee -a ${log_file} >&2)
}

setup

echo "hello world"
echo "hello again"
```

I'm testing forcing all echo's to go to stdout and a log file simultaneously. I've seen this behavior before in scripts and have always wondered:

- Why does this happen?
- How to make it so that I don't have to type return to exit the script?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have to hit enter. You are already at the next prompt. Try typing a command and hitting enter.

The problem is that you've raced the output and the next prompt being printed to the screen.

So your prompt gets printed *before* the standard error output gets printed so you "lose" your cursor positioning.

Clearing the screen, with Ctrl-L say, will also get you "back" to your prompt.